# My Incredible Bite

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Size of my fist or size of dust
>   Color of night, rainbow or white
>   If I check health, 
> I'm unhealthy myself
>   Sweeter or hotter,
>   Or eyes will water
>   At my incredible bite
>   **What am I?**

**NOTE**

This *has* got 10 up-votes in the [sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox/5280#5280)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure this is

> pepper

although there is one couplet I don't think I understand. [EDITED: But now I do; see below.]

Size of my fist or size of dust

> A whole bell/capsicum pepper is roughly fist-sized. Ground-up black pepper seeds are dust-like.

Color of night, rainbow or white

> The pepper seeds we use ground for seasoning are usually black or white. Chili peppers and sweet peppers are commonly red, orange, yellow or green. (I have yet to see a blue one, so maybe "rainbow" is stretching it a bit.)

If I check health,
I'm unhealthy myself

> I confess I'm not sure what this is about. [EDITED to add:] After writing all the rest of this answer I happened to look at the riddle sandbox and saw a mention of "the Dr. bit" at which all became clear: "Dr Pepper" is the name of a soft drink; doctors check your health but soft drinks are usually not at all good for you

Sweeter or hotter,

> There are "sweet" peppers with no capsaicin in them, hot chili peppers with lots of capsaicin, and black/white pepper seeds that come from an entirely different plant and are hot for different reasons.

Or eyes will water
At my incredible bite

> Capsaicin from Capsicum sp., and piperine in Piper nigrum.

Comment: just asking , did you read this question first here or in sandbox ?

Comment: Here. (I read the question, solved it apart from one couplet, posted my answer, went to the sandbox out of curiosity and saw a remark there that made it obvious what was going on with the couplet I'd missed.)

Comment: This is indeed correct